# Таблица истинности

Tags: логические-выражения

Возможно ли выражение, которое имеет такую же таблицу истинности как у (a &&(and) b), но без использования &&(and), а только используя ||(or) и !(not)?

Comment: да, возможно ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать законы де Моргана - `!(!a || !b)`.